# How do I get better looking results with Sandstone texture paint?

Tags: painting, paint, texture

I am painting a small bathroom with Sandstone paint that I bought in Lowe's (for non-US users, this is big chain of home improvement/remodeling stores).

The result is just terrible. First, it requires multiple passes just to hide the white base ($50/can, and I am finishing a second can. $100 just to paint a small bathroom is rather excessive). Second, I can't get the paint to lay uniformly on the wall: sand (the aggregate in the paint) ends up as big, visible build-ups on the wall.

What am I doing wrong and how do I do it right?

Comment: Maybe it's you, or maybe it's just crap!  I wouldn't buy any architectural coating product in a home improvement store. First stop would be Sherwin Williams. Even some of the acrylic latex paint from places like Home Depot is just awful. Six coats later, it's still not hiding and you're out of paint, and tired from pushing so hard to get it to flow.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. Are you using a 'textured roller'? - if not, don't use texture paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment on the sandstone paint, but I'd suggest getting the primer tinted something close to the final color so that you're not using the expensive paint try to cover a white base.

I'd also follow Kaz's advice above regarding quality paints.  You usually do get what you pay for.

Answer (score 2):

All kinds of designers paint require the experience and skill of a professional artist or painter to achieve a faux finish. One unfamiliar with such finishes could waste gallons of paint, tons of nerves and never even get close to the way it's supposed to look.

Adding color to the primer would be helpful, but learning real faux painting techniques; even more so.